# Replace image content with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps

I have a page where I show an image within some defined dimensions. I now want to invoke Google maps on a button click and show it within that dimensions itself. How can I do it in JavaScript and Angular JS?

P.S. I suppose it can be done by creating new JSP and link it to the button. But I want to update only the image portion not the whole page since it will take more time to load.

```js
"use strict";

angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

 // variable to hold a map
 var map;
 
 // variable to hold current active InfoWindow
 var activeInfoWindow ;  

 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
 // initialize function  
 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
   
  
  // map options - lots of options available here 
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom : 8,
    draggable: true,
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.5622, 22.6141),
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  
  // create map in div called map-canvas using map options defined above
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);
  // define two Google Map LatLng objects representing geographic points
  var kalamata = new google.maps.LatLng(37.0422, 22.1141);
  var athens  = new google.maps.LatLng(37.9833, 23.7333);

  // place two markers
  fnPlaceMarkers(kalamata,"Kalamata");
  fnPlaceMarkers(athens,"Athens");
  
  window.setTimeout(function(){
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  },10);
  
  $scope.container = true;
       
       $scope.toggle = function(){
         $scope.container = !$scope.container;
       };
       

 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
 // create markers on the map
 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
 function fnPlaceMarkers(myLocation,myCityName){
   
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position : myLocation
  });
 
  // Renders the marker on the specified map
  marker.setMap(map); 

  // create an InfoWindow
  var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();   
  
  // add content to your InfoWindow
  infoWnd.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + 'Welcome to ' +  myCityName + '</div>');
  
  // add listener on InfoWindow - close last infoWindow  before opening new one 
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
   
   //Close active window if exists - [one might expect this to be default behaviour no?]    
   if(activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();

   // Open InfoWindow
   infoWnd.open(map, marker);

   // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
   activeInfoWindow = infoWnd;
  });        
 }

    }]);
```

```html
<img src=<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/images/io6.jpg style="width: 1245px; height: 290px;" ng-show="container">
<div id="googleMap" style="width:1245px;height:290px; display: inline-block;" ng-show="!container"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Look how to ask in this address: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just hide the image on button click and show google map

```
<img src="dummy.jpg" ng-show="!container">
<div id="googleMap" ng-show="container"></div>
<button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>

$scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.container = !$scope.container;
    if($scope.container){ 
      setTimeout(function( {google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')});
    }
};
```

[example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/huH7Uj5SCTUS5nAtayXv?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is working perfectly when map is shown on first load and image after the button is clicked.  I want the image to appear first, so I changed $scope.container = true; to $scope.container = false; Image is coming properly but when I hit the button, map doesn't show up. No errors also. When I inspect the element then it loads automatically.  I tried changing the parameter in your example which is responding perfectly without any errors.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add, that google map doesn't load on hidden div you have to trigger resize event manually i will update plunker

Comment: I tried adding google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); but no luck. Can you update Plunker?

Comment: Added HTML snippet and script

Comment: you have to trigger it after you show map div, i updated my answer